# Replace NULL with empty string

Tags: sql-server

Due to precedence set within my organization, I need to replace NULL values in certain columns (roughly 15-20) with the empty string. While the solution comes quite easily in more traditional languages, I'm struggling with how to do this in T-SQL. Can anybody point me in the right direction? Much appreciated.

Comment: SET My_String = "" WHERE My_String IS NULL AND Other_Conditions;? Not an expert SQL Server guy, but unless Microsoft made the same mistake as Oracle where the empty string and NULL are considered the same.

Comment: That'll do wonderfully, thank you. I should have known that, must be getting late...

Comment: @Vérace If you want to post an answer, I'll accept it. Otherwise ill probably just delete the question in a bit. Doesn't provide much value to the site

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not an expert SQL Server guy. However, Since Microsoft haven't made the same mistake as Oracle where the [empty string and NULL are considered the same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13278879/470530), this should work:

```
UPDATE TableName
SET My_String = '' 
WHERE My_String IS NULL 
AND Other_Conditions;
```